# React: Vaadin grid sort column TypeError: Cannot call a class constructor without new

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vaadin-grid

I would like to use the vaadin grid in a react project. Especially I‘m interessed in the sorting and filtering functionality which looks nice! So I tried to use the  as described on the vaadin component page, but got always an „TypeError: Class constructor GridColumnElement cannot be invoked without 'new'„ exception.
Does anyone knows what I‘m doing wrong? Or does anyone has a working example to share with me?

```
import React from 'react';

import '@vaadin/vaadin-button';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-sort-column';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-form-layout';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-checkbox';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-combo-box';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-text-field';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-custom-field';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-date-picker'
import '@vaadin/vaadin-tabs'
import '@vaadin/vaadin-icons'

class Example extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Will called whenever the component is rendered to the DOM for the first time.
   */
  componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", () => {
        this.refs.grid.dataProvider = this.load;
      });
      this.refs.grid.size = 20; 

  }

  load(params, callback) {
      fetch(URL, 
        {
            method: 'get'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => callback(data, data.length));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>            
            <vaadin-grid ref="grid" theme="column-borders row-stripes wrap-cell-content">
                <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable path="id" header="ID"></vaadin-grid-sort-column>
                <vaadin-grid-column resizable header="Name"></vaadin-grid-column>
            </vaadin-grid>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

[exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JssCO.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code example of the issue.

Comment: i have a similar problem with lit-element in combination with parceljs. The only interesting discussion of similar problem i found is here: https://github.com/DeMoorJasper/parcel-plugin-svelte/issues/44.